# Use constant IPv4LL (link-local) address in "dhcp" mode

Tags: ipv4, zeroconf, connman, link-local

**Situation**:

I'm using [ConnMan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConnMan) 1.41 on an embedded device. The interface configuration looks as follows:

```
[ethernet_deadbeefcafe_cable]
Name=Wired
AutoConnect=true
IPv4.method=auto
IPv6.method=auto
IPv6.privacy=disabled
```

DHCP works. When there is no DHCP server, ConnMan falls back to IPv4LL (you may know it as mDns, Bonjour or Zeroconf). That is, the device gets a random IP in the 169.254.0.0/16 link-local range. But the IP changes on every reboot. However, other embedded devices conveniently use a constant seed (e.g. MAC) to always generate the same IP.

**Question**:

- How to configure ConnMan to use the same IPv4LL address across reboots?

**Tried**:

- I found no [option](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/connman/connman-service.config.5.en.html) to configure that for IPv4.
- For IPv6 there is `IPv6.privacy=enabled`, which works.
- Looking at the [code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/tree/gdhcp/client.c?h=1.41) (`ipv4ll_start`, line 1372), I see no hint for a configuration option.

I will now try to manually patch it in the code. But on first glance this will probably break IP collision handling.